# Exposed C++ lib to go with swig (in Mac OS X)

Tags: c++, macos, go, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to expose a C++ [example](https://github.com/swig/swig/tree/master/Examples/go/simple) to Go,

I'm doing this:

```
swig -intgosize 64 -go example.i
go tool 8g -+ example.go
eval $(go env) # fill in the appropiate vars
go tool 8c -I ${GOROOT}/pkg/${GOOS}_${GOARCH} -D _64BIT=1 -v example_gc.c 
go tool pack grc example.a example.8 example_gc.8
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
g++ -O2 -fPIC -march=nocona -c example_wrap.c
g++ -O2 -fPIC -march=nocona -c example.c
gcc -shared -o example.so example_wrap.o example.o
##g++ -dynamclib example.o example_wrap.o -o example.so
go tool 8g runme.go
go tool 8l -o runme runme.8
```

All the lines except for the last one works, however in the last command I get:

```
  /go/simple/example.Void.Swigcptr: /go/simple/example.a(example.8): go%2ebuiltin.error.Error: redefinition
  go.importpath.runtime/cgo.(0): not defined
  type./go/simple/example.Void(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gclocals·3(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gcargs·3(0): not defined
  go.string."Swigcptr"(0): not defined
  go.string."SwigcptrVoid"(0): not defined
  go.string."example"(0): not defined
  type.*/go/simple/example.SwigcptrVoid(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gclocals·2(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gcargs·2(0): not defined
  type./go/simple/example.SwigcptrVoid(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gclocals·1(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gcargs·1(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gclocals·0(0): not defined
  /go/simple/example.gcargs·0(0): not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: If you rename `example.i` to `example.swigcxx`, can you build your package with a simple `go build` invocation?  You shouldn't need these manual steps since Go 1.2.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, in the go repo they have some examples in misc/swig and some people comment they have problems with these minimal examples, core developers say that it will be ready for go 1.3(see this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6630&q=swig&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary))